# gcc fail to expand macro when passing a lambda as its parameter? - gcc bug

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to implement a simple ScopeGuard and meet this promblem.

following is the code:

main.cpp

```
#define ON_SCOPE_EXIT(callback)

int main()
{
    int a,b;

   //this works well
    ON_SCOPE_EXIT([a]{});

    //fail to compile (actually preprocessor fails)
    ON_SCOPE_EXIT([a,b]{});
    return 0;
}
```

```

compile with:
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -o test

the compiler says:

> main.cpp:14:26: error: macro "ON_SCOPE_EXIT" passed 2 arguments, but
>   takes just 1
>        ON_SCOPE_EXIT([a,b]{});
>                             ^ main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:14:5: error: ‘ON_SCOPE_EXIT’ was not declared in this scope
>        ON_SCOPE_EXIT([a,b]{});

My g++ version is g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4).
However ,it dosn't work for g++ 5.4.0 either.

Comment: It's the *comma* that does it. Try wrapping the whole lambda in parentheses.

Comment: comma in macro, so you have 2 arguments with `ON_SCOPE_EXIT([a,b]{});`. `[a` and `b]{}`.

Comment: Why using MACRO btw, regular class does the trick (you just have to name it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! BTW, who's responsible for this problem? The developer, c++ standard, or gcc?

Comment: The developer is responsible for using a C preprocessor macro when C++ code would be better suited.